# Find eigenvector and eigenvalues X1 X2

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

\begin{vmatrix} 7/2 & 2\\ 2 & 3\end{vmatrix}

The characteristic equation is |A - λ I | = 0

$(\frac{7}{2}-λ)(3- λ)-4=0 $

$ λ_1= \frac{13-\sqrt{65}}{4}  $ $λ_2 = \frac{13+\sqrt{65}}{4}  $

so (A- $\frac{13-\sqrt{65}}{4}$I)x=0

$ 2x_1 $ + ($ \frac{\sqrt{65}-1}{4})x_2  $

$x_1$ = $ \frac{1-\sqrt{65}}{8}x_2  $

this is so far what I got,,, and I want to know is it correct? then I will proceed λ2 thanks.

Comment: Seems to be fine. Remember that you can check it, by simply calculating $Av_1$, where $v_1$ is an eigenvector, and checking whether it's equal to $\lambda_1v_1$, where $\lambda_1$ is the corresponding eigenvalue.

Comment: You already determined it. Just (for example) pick $x_2=1$, then $x_1=\frac{1-\sqrt{65}}{8}$, so $v_1=(\frac{1-\sqrt{65}}{8},1)$. Do you understand what happened?

Comment: The notation $\{1,\frac{1-\sqrt{65}}{8}$ is no good, but yes, your idea is correct.

Comment: @B.Pasternak another question is when i solve$(A- \frac{13-\sqrt{65}}{4}I)x $ there's another answer about $x_1$ , $\frac{13-\sqrt{65}}{4}x_1$+2$X_2$=0 then different verctors...

Answer (score 0):

When I solve $(A-\lambda I){\bf{v}}=0$ to get the eigenvectors for $\lambda_1=\tfrac{1}{4}(13-\sqrt{65})$, I get
\begin{align}
0&=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{7}{2}-\tfrac{1}{4}(13-\sqrt{65})&2\\
2&3-\tfrac{1}{4}(13-\sqrt{65})
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
(\frac{7}{2}-\tfrac{1}{4}(13-\sqrt{65}))v_1+2v_2\\
2v_1+(3-\frac{1}{4}(13-\sqrt{65})v_2
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
and thus the two equations
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4}(1+\sqrt{65})v_1+2v_2&=0\implies v_2=-\frac{1}{8}(1+\sqrt{65})v_1,\\
2v_1+\frac{1}{4}(\sqrt{65}-1)&=0\implies v_1=-\frac{1}{8}(\sqrt{65}-1)v_2,
\end{align}
which gives me the eigenvector
\begin{align}
{\bf{v}}_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-\frac{1}{8}(1+\sqrt{65}),
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
or equivalently
\begin{align}
{\bf{v}}_1=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{8}(1-\sqrt{65})\\
1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Note that since the these two vectors lie each other's span, since multiplication by $\pm\frac{1}{8}(1\mp\sqrt{65})$ of one gives the other (I'm sure you can see this by just calculating). I don't know how you got that other equality, but I'm guessing you just miscalculated something somewhere. I hope this helps.